# Discussion Module emails only going to last person to comment

Tags: forum

I have a strange problem. We are using EE2.5.3 and Discussion Forum3.1.9. I also have Forum Subscribe2.3.2 installed. On our forums, if someone enters a new reply to a topic which has several people subscribed, the module will send an email only to the last person who replied to that thread. I have tested by changing the email protocol and uninstalling Forum Subscribe. I am currently using SMTP as the email protocol.

Any help or other ways to troubleshoot would be appreciated.

Edit:
After further trouble shooting, it appears that the issue is with the thread subscription mechanism in EE. If a new thread is started, everyone subscribed to that forum with Forum Subscribe receives an email as they should. However, if all of those people then subscribe to the thread in EE, when anyone responds, the response only goes to the last person that responded (if they have left selected the "Notify me via email..." checkbox). Any ideas?

Thanks,
   Steve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to give a full answer of how we fixed this issue:

We found that in system/expressionengine/modules/forum/mod.forum_core.php at line 6576, there is code to change field "notification_sent" to "y" once an email is sent. However, once that field is set to "y", no further emails go out. To make this work as we need, we modified the code to leave that field at "n".

Original line 6576:
`$this->EE->db->set('notification_sent', 'y');`

Modified line:
`$this->EE->db->set('notification_sent', 'n');`

If anyone is subscribed to that thread now, they will continue to receive email updates until they unsubscribe.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a bug that needs to be reported to EllisLab. You can [**report bugs on the EllisLab website**](https://support.ellislab.com/bugs)... need to login first.

Comment: You're probably right. After further investigation, I found that in mod.forum_core.php, whenever a notice is sent out, the field "notification_sent" is set to "y" in table "exp_forum_subscriptions". I haven't a clue why that is done but once it is set to "y", no further emails are sent. I modified the file to leave that field at "n" and it is working fine.

Comment: Tada... Make sure you start a "hacks.txt" file if you changed core code to make sure you are covered with future upgrades.